# how to transform 120V AC to 5V DC 5A load using flyback transformer circuit? Setting frequency - low cost, low footprint - change load capacity

Tags: transformer, ac-dc, high-current

i am using a flyback transformer circuit to keep the footprint small and cost efficient. Its been suggested to me to keep the frequency high so the transformer can remain small.

how is the frequency set in a flyback converter circuit?

Which components are different when transforming a load of 400mA or transforming a load of 5A? (i am using 5A, though most of what i see on Google is people looking to transform to 400mA for 30-60V DC)

is this something i can find load measurements on my components for, if so, which components measurements should be reviewed when changing the load capacity to a greater amperage?

this is my application .. 120V AC -> flyback transformer circuit -> 5V DC 5A power draw

the others i have seen are 30V DC -> flyback transformer circuit -> 5V DC 400mA power draw

the power draw is much greater in my circuit, i am looking to find what changes there are.

the flyback converter circuit i am designing is going to change AC to DC also. I think (don't know, looking for confirmation on) a typical flyback transformer changes DC to AC and then back again in it's typical application. So it does not matter whether it is AC or DC on its first input?

i am going to use a tool called WEBENCH - its available from Texas Instruments https://webench.ti.com/ . suggested to me by @user4578 on the post that lead to this 
[Which buck converter can be used for 120 V AC to 5 V AC rated at 5 amps?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501393/which-buck-converter-can-be-used-for-120-v-ac-to-5-v-ac-rated-at-5-amps?noredirect=1#comment1279038_501393) - on that post it was decided to use an isolated transformer circuit to step down from 120V AC instead of the buck converter i had originally intended.

Comment: From the question and your comments I am guessing you have a lot to learn and you are using this project to do it. Is your learning stops with power supply or does your application have more to it? The thing is - modern AC power supplies are a) extremely cheap and b) quite complex. So, what I would recommend - save yourself a lot of troubles by buying ready-made power brick and do your learning on the application itself.

Comment: well theres a lot more too this and it's worth the time to learn to build AC power supply. Been here a long ways and the flyback transformer is the answer i'm looking for. Understanding the circuit is important. Not so complex to those who understand it (those who have built it). Reading the question you see it's just specifications to using high amperage and setting the frequency, together.

Comment: I agree with you, it is not too complex to those who understands it. Considering that you keep using "flyback transformer" (aka LOPT) while asking about "flyback converter", I don't think that you do.

Comment: my understanding is that flyback transformers are used within a flyback converter "circuit". And that there isn't a particular flyback transformer that is just a flyback transformer, but a transformer in general. flyback transformer means a transformer that is in use with a flyback converter "circuit" and it's referring to just the transformer in that circuit.

Comment: the design of this transformer commonly marks it as a flyback transformer.

Comment: "there isn't a particular flyback transformer" and that is where you are mistaken. The FBT is actually a coupled inductor with a gapped core. It is designed to _store_ energy during first part of the cycle and then release it when field collapses (or "flies back" if you wish). In contrast, "a transformer in general" is designed to _pass_ energy from primary to secondary immediately and with minimal losses.

Comment: "flyback transformer means a transformer that is in use with a flyback converter circuit" Flyback transformers were invented as high voltage sources e.g. for driving deflection coils in CRTs. I believe it was long before what we now call flyback converters. Note that the load (deflection yoke) is _connected to primary winding_ of the flyback transformer, which is a major difference from the use of transformers _including those in flyback converters_, where load is connected to secondary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is the frequency set in a flyback converter circuit?

The frequency is set by the switcher IC.  To find out the details you must look at the datasheet for specific chips.  Its going to be different for every one of them.

- Sometimes its a fixed frequency determined by the chip design and you cant change it.
- Sometimes you add an external component (resistor or capacitor) to
  set the frequency.
- Sometimes there is a pin that can select from a set of frequencies by
  applying a voltage.
- Sometimes you use a separate oscillator to set the frequency.

As far ad determining what a reasonable frequency is...

- Somewhere in the 100KHz to 1MHz range is pretty typical, but higher and lower is not impossible.
- It depends on your transformer.  The transformer will probably only
  be rated at    a specific frequency, or range of frequencies.  Using
  it outside of    whats specified you don't have any guarantee on
  performance.  So use what the datasheet says if you can.
- Your switcher IC will also have some frequency limitations that are
  stated in the datasheet.
- Higher frequencies can use smaller transformers but have higher
  switching and core losses. so its a trade.

> Which components are different when transforming a load of 400mA or
>   transforming a load of 5A? (i am using 5A, though most of what i see
>   on Google is people looking to transform to 400mA for 30-60V DC)

All other things being equal the transformer is going to be 12.5 X larger for 5A vs 400mA.

Wurth electronics has a great tool called "Red Expert" that can help with transformer selection.  They have a whole section in the tool to select fly-back transformers for offline switchers.

https://redexpert.we-online.com/redexpert/

> is this something i can find load measurements on my components for,
>   if so, which components measurements should be reviewed when changing
>   the load capacity to a greater amperage?

When increasing the amperage, all the power path components need to be reviewed.

- Rectifier Didoes, wattage rating increases proportional to current.
- Transformer, volume increases proportional to output power
- Switcher IC, need to check that it can handle current levels.
- Switching transistors (if any)
- Bulk holdup capacitors probably increase in size proportional to output power level.

> the flyback converter circuit i am designing is going to change AC to
>   DC also. I think (don't know, looking for confirmation on) a typical
>   flyback transformer changes DC to AC and then back again in it's
>   typical application. So it does not matter whether it is AC or DC on
>   its first input?

Some converter designs work with either AC or DC input, some only on AC.  There is no universal answer here.  Usually if there is a full bridge rectifier at the front end of the design, then there is a good chance it will work with DC also.

Comment: the transformer is going to be 12.5 X larger than with a 500mA  load? i don't know. I have two chargers, one 400mA, one 4 amp, and they both fit in the palm of my hand. How can a transformer be kept very small with high voltage?

Comment: The 12.5X figure is for "all other things being equal".  The energy (E) stored in a transformer core is proportional to the square of the flux and the core volume.  Each core material has some maximum flux at which it saturates and can no longer store any more energy.  The maximum output wattage you can get out of the transformer, switching at frequency f, is going to be E * f.  So for a given frequency and core material you must increase the size proportional to the output wattage.  You can always just use another core material or frequency.  The proportional size is just a rough guideline.

Answer (score 1):

> *how is the frequency set in a flyback converter circuit?*

There is a chip (usually) that operates at a certain frequency, quite often 100 kHz but can be significantly lower or, up to a few hundred kHz higher.

> *Which components are different when transforming a load of 400mA or
>   transforming a load of 5A?*

If the converter is designed to deliver up to 5 amps then there is no difference. If designed to only output 400 mA then, to use it for 5 amps will pretty much change every component.

> *is this something i can find load measurements on my components for*

You need to look at various flyback converter designs to get a feel for things.

> *which components measurements should be reviewed when changing the
>   load capacity to a greater amperage?*

I wouldn't recommend this - trying to make a low power flyback converter suitable for a significantly higher power will require wholesale changes and is much more trouble than it's worth. You would redesign completely.

> *So it does not matter whether it is AC or DC on its first input?*

Usually it doesn't matter but, you do need to put a bridge rectifier (and capacitor) on the front end of a flyback DC to DC converter to make it suitable for AC applications but, there may be a lot of other details that need to change too in order to meet EMI specifications. A 30 volt rated DC to DC converter with a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor will not be able to work with AC voltages higher than about 20 V. It has to be designed properly as in all circuits.

Comment: going to update with a circuit diagram.. i'd use a chip to set the frequency. then a bridge rectifier and smoothing (filtering) capacitor before the input to flyback transformer.
the circuit is anything i want to make it so if a flyback transformer can accept AC then it could be recitfied after it passes through (still AC current). Is there a benefit to doing so? And is a 30 volt rated DC to DC converter then converting that 30V DC input to AC before it goes through the flyback transformer?

Comment: is it wrong in thinking that a DC to DC converter takes the DC input as a way to be compatible with DC inputs (for a prefab solution) and then converts it to AC before going through the flyback transformer? (DC -> AC -> FLYBACK TRANSFORMER -> DC) if this were true then there'd be no reason to use a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor before the flyback transformer, as i don't have this prefab solution included in my circuit.

Comment: Please DO NOT move the goal posts. I'm not going get involved in a teach-in for how flyback converters work in this specific question and answer area. If that is what you want, then raise a specific question about a recognized flyback design (not your own) and then that can then be correctly answered. If your aim is to get a tear down of your own design and evolve that design through comments and answers then this is not the site for that type of question.

Comment: I am going to post a separate question referring to a particular flyback converter schematic that is providing lower output amperage from the same input source voltage.

Comment: Good idea - keep questions as direct as possible.